# Filter rows based on the count of unique values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to count the unique values of column A and filter out the column with values greater than say 2

```
 A C
Apple 4
Orange 5
Apple 3
Mango 5
Orange 1
```

I have calculated the unique values but not able to figure out how to filer them `df.value_count()`

I want to filter column A that have greater than 2, expected Dataframe

```
A B
Apple 4
Orange 5
Apple 3
Orange 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) should be called on a Series (single column) rather than a DataFrame:

```
counts = df['A'].value_counts()
```

Giving:

```
A
Apple     2
Mango     1
Orange    2
dtype: int64
```

You can then filter this to only keep those >= 2 and use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to filter your DataFrame:

```
filtered = counts[counts >= 2]
df[df['A'].isin(filtered.index)]
```

Giving:

```
        A  C
0   Apple  4
1  Orange  5
2   Apple  3
4  Orange  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `duplicated` with parameter `keep=False`:

```
df[df.duplicated(['A'], keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
        A  C
0   Apple  4
1  Orange  5
2   Apple  3
4  Orange  1
```